# Kali Linux wifi card detected but not working

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking

Iam using Kali linux for a while now. But the wifi doesnt seems to be working well. When I typed 'ifconfig' in the command prompt it shows the wlan0 network card and even the HW Addr but it doesnt show available connections in the network manager.

Please help.

PS: wash and airodump also doesnt show any results of the available networks, though monitor mode is getting enabled when I use airmon-ng.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kali Linux only supports Wireless cards that use certain specific CHIPSETS in them. You might get internet connectivity for Kali if you are running it from a Virtual Machine since gets its connectivity from the host OS.

However, Kali does not recognize your wireless card because it most like doesn't support the chipset it uses.

There are 2 possible solutions for this.

1- (Is not the most convenient but I'm just putting it out there):  Get a new wireless cards that uses a chipset from [this list of supported chipsets and cards](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compatibility_drivers#which_is_the_best_card_to_buy)
You also want to make sure the card you get supports wireless packet injection

2- Just get a wireless USB adapter from the that has one of the supported chipsets.

[Any adapter from this list will most likely do just fine](http://www.wirelesshack.org/top-kali-linux-compatible-usb-adapters-dongles-2015.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried figuring out the chipset of my wireless card and it seems that a lot of users have this problem. My wireless card is RealTek rtl8723be and installing drivers for this is a complicated task it seems. I tried following solutions from a lots of different forums but I was unable to succeed. I'am planning to just install kali linux 2.0 now. If you can help me install this driver for kali linux : Linux jaimatadi 3.18.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.18.6-1~kali2 (2015-03-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux , It will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sure I can help! If you have issues throughout the installation process just post another question and tag me. But getting a USB adapter will be the quickest solution as there would be no need to look for and install additional drivers. Also if my answered fully answered your question please mark it as the accepted one.